# Rename legends in subplots: matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a data frame `stats` with two columns `Old` and `New`. I plot them in two separate subplots but I would like to rename my legends but leave subtitles as they are. `plt.legend(labels= ['Stats'])` renames only one subplot legend though. Will appreciate your help.

```
stats.plot(kind='bar',
               grid=False, subplots=True, 
               figsize=(20,10), fontsize=16, 
               color='#2E9240', 
               sharex=True, sharey=True)

plt.tick_params(
    axis='x',          # changes apply to the x-axis
    which='both',      # both major and minor ticks are affected
    bottom='off',      # ticks along the bottom edge are off
    top='off',         # ticks along the top edge are off
    labelbottom='off') # labels along the bottom edge are off

plt.legend(labels= ['Stats'])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataFrame.plot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html?highlight=dataframe%20plot#pandas.DataFrame.plot) returns the plot axes or an array of axes for each subplot. Use the axes to change their legends.

```
axes = stats.plot(kind='bar',
                  grid=False, subplots=True, 
                  figsize=(20,10), fontsize=16, 
                  color='#2E9240', 
                  sharex=True, sharey=True)
for ax in axes:
    ax.legend(['Stats'])
```